# How to change where spack installs package?

Tags: spack

Is there a way to have spack install software at a location of my choosing?

For example, if I do:

```
spack install netcdf-c
```

Then spack will install netcdf-c in a directory like:

```
/home/ed/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu21.04-broadwell/gcc-10.3.0/netcdf-c-4.8.0-4zwtnn73atpc5ojmpigo7utmwzds7qrq
```

Is it possible to have spack install netcdf-c at /usr/local instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. The [preferred way](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/replace_conda_homebrew.html) would be to make an environment and use a spack view to put the install (or symlink to the install binaries) where you want them.

If you wanted to hard code the install path this can be done as well through the spack `config.yaml` (documentation [here](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_yaml.html#spack-settings-config-yaml); look at the `install_tree:root` ).